# Install Debian on Mikrotik RB 2011 routerboard

Tags: debian, networking, hardware, router, mips

Is there any way to install Debian sid on Mikrotik RB 2011?
Seems to Debian MIPS port not support this type of cpu (Atheros 600MHz 74K MIPS big-endian), I already install OpenWRT on this device, need to install Debian.

List of Debian images: https://d-i.debian.org/daily-images/
Debian MIPS port: https://www.debian.org/ports/mips/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this:

[DebianWRT](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianWRT)

You can either use a full Debian Linux using an OpenWRT kernel, or chroot to Debian from OpenWRT.